# Can we get the post clicks count of a post made in Facebook using graph api v2.3?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

My requirement is to get the post clicks count of a post made in Facebook(wall or page) using Graph API v2.3.

Please suggest!

Comment: Have you read the documentation? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Insights are only available for pages, but you can do something like this:

`/v2.3/<page>?fields=posts{insights.metric(<metric_name>)}`

where `<page>` is the name or id of your page and `<metric_name>` is one of the metrics for posts from this page:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights

Comment: Do you have a link reference to that query pattern? I don't see it the link in your answer.

Comment: It's a combination of the insights page I linked above, which shows you what fields are available, and the syntax for making nested requests from this page:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3